# A sequence which tends to 0 but its reciprocal tends to another value

Tags: analysis

I have a homework assigned that is asking me to find a sequence $b_n$, whose limit is $0$ but when plugged into the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}$  $f(b_n) = 1$.

So I thought that I had to find a sequence which does tend to 0 but reciprocal tends to a value of $2/(2k-1)\pi$, since that'd when $\sin(1/x) = 1$. But so far I'm not able to find such a sequence and would like some tips.

I'm sorry if formating is bad, this is my first post.

Comment: $b_n:=\frac{2}{(2n-1)\pi}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. You solved your own problem, didn't you?

Comment: Your idea looks solid.  what's wrong with it?  If $b_n=\frac 2{(2n-1)\pi}$ then $b_n\to 0$ but $\sin \frac 1{b_n}=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: My problem is that since if we take $b_n$ = $2/(2n-1)pi$ then we'll have $1/b_n$ = $(2n-1)pi/2$ but wouldn't the limit of that be infinity

Comment: you don’t care about $\lim 1/b_n$. You only care about $\lim\sin(1/b_n)$. And you did that right.